# Why can't my Android Emulator recognize my words through the microphone?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, voice-recognition, microphone

I am attempting to develop a Voice search feature for an app I am currently developing, but due to unfortunate circumstances, I only have the Android emulator available to me, and no physical Android phone.

I have been trying to get the Microphone on the Android Emulator to hear my voice, just through the normal Google Search, but it does not seem to be able to capture the words I am saying.

I have tested this on two different emulators, Pixel XL and Pixel 3a, both running Android Oreo.

I have gone in the emulator settings and made sure that "Virtual Microphone uses host audio input" is turned on.

The Emulator microphone seems to recognize when I'm talking, and the volume at which I'm talking at, indicated by the microphone interface/animation, but it never is able to transcribe any of the words. It always return an empty result after attempting a voice search.

I am on a 2019 MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina. I have confirmed the microphone on this computer works fine by testing it on several Voice to Text websites. I have also tried launching the emulator from terminal, without any success.

If anyone has any advice, that would be great!

Comment: Possibly related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157223337